# Response code 200 but nothing is scraped by the Object Debugger

Tags: facebook, https, facebook-opengraph

I am running a URL through the Object Debugger, but it seems nothing is scraped for [this URL](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=https://www.propellerheads.se/shop/index.cfm?fuseaction=product_detail&ID=10726&Cat=1000). I get the following error message:

```
Could not retrieve data from URL.
```

Looking at the [scraped data](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=https://www.propellerheads.se/shop/index.cfm?fuseaction=product_detail&ID=10726&Cat=1000), only a single line has been scraped, which doesn't even correspond to the content in the the scraped page.

**Edit:**

This is caused by whitespace before the initial <html> tag. Removing any leading whitespace solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you use gzip in your page, disable it and try again. That fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this URL, Facebook tries to download but your server is not returning any data.
When we see this URL, you'll found

```
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.propellerheads.se%2Fshop%2Findex.cfm%3Ffuseaction%3Dproduct_detail

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I already stated in the question. Somehow FB receives empty content instead of the actual content.